# Moq.Setup method with T?

Tags: .net, unit-testing, mocking, moq

I have the following methods to mock:

```
AddParameter<T>(string parameterName, T value)
AddParameter<T>(string parameterName, T? value) where T : struct;


private void SetupAddParameter<T>(){
    mock.Setup(u => u.AddParameter<T>(Moq.It.IsAny<string>(), Moq.It.IsAny<T>()))...
    mock.Setup(u => u.AddParameter<T>(Moq.It.IsAny<string>(), Moq.It.IsAny<T?>())) -> not working
}
```

How can I mock the second method?

Comment: Unless you have a `where T : class` constraint on the first and a `where T : struct` on the second, they aren't actually any different.

Comment: @TrevorPilley The second has where T : struct

Comment: The first doesn't compile either, you need to specify a type, you can't say `It.IsAny<T>()`

Comment: @TrevorPilley This mocks are within a method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, you can't do both setups in the same method, you need to do the struct version in its own method with a `where T : strut` restriction:

```
private void SetupAddParameter<T>()
{
    // Setup for AddParameter<T>(string parameterName, T value);
    mock.Setup(u => u.AddParameter<T>(Moq.It.IsAny<string>(), Moq.It.IsAny<T>()));
}

private void SetupAddParameter<T>() where T : struct
{
    // Setup for AddParameter<T>(string parameterName, T? value) where T : struct;
    mock.Setup(u => u.AddParameter<T>(Moq.It.IsAny<string>(), Moq.It.IsAny<T?>()));
}
```

Comment: I'm getting "An exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred in Moq.dll" when calling: 
AddParameter<Datetime>("TEST",null)

Comment: After searching for this error I think there is a bug on moq: https://github.com/Moq/moq4/issues/90, https://github.com/Moq/moq4/issues/114